# DTC testing fail

Tags: sql-server, dns, msdtc

I am testing DTC service between our app and DB servers which are in different domains.

To resolve DNS issue,  have modified the hosts file and the network file with  IP and server name, DBNETWORK entries in both DB server and app server

We have firewall and required ports open between these servers and DB test connection is also successful from app server.

Ports opened bi-directional: 135, 1433-1434, 5100-5200, 8853-8856, 25, 27975, 8770, pop3, 8860

We have added port range 5100-5200 in component services default protocol properties and restarted both the servers.

We created a ODBC Data source on application server and when we do DTC testing using DTCtester.exe from cmd prompt, we get the below error.

**Initializing DTC
Beginning DTC Transaction
Enlisting Connection in Transaction
Error:
SQLSTATE=25S12,Native error=-2147168242,msg='[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]
Distributed transaction error'
Error:
SQLSTATE=24000,Native error=0,msg=[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid cur
sor state
Typical Errors in DTC Output When
a.  Firewall Has Ports Closed
-OR-
b.  Bad WINS/DNS entries
-OR-
c.  Misconfigured network
-OR-
d.  Misconfigured SQL Server machine that has multiple netcards.
Aborting DTC Transaction
Releasing DTC Interface Pointers
Successfully Released pTransaction Pointer.**

Tried msdtc uninstall , install and resetlog but it did not help.
DTC service is also started and running.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

We did trouble shooting using DTCPing. We got "gethostbyname can not resolve" error when we tried DTC ping from DB server to App server. We noticed that hosts file did not correctly pointing to the app server and corrected it with app server's IP and server name details. then DTC ping was successful and so DTCtester too.